# Limit the duration display for a popup in Qt

Tags: qt, popup, qtimer

I would like to have a popup which lasts only 20 seconds. I think use a QTimer, but is it possible to set a dynamic message which indicates the seconds remaining?

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from QDialog and use two QTimer events. The first set to trigger after 20 seconds and then close the dialog and the second to trigger every second and update a QLabel with the remaining time. So when the QDialog is displayed you'd do something like this: -

```
m_DialogClose = startTimer(20 * 1000); // 20 seconds
m_RemainingTime = startTimer(1 * 1000); // 1 second
```

Then you override the timerEvent function in your dialog: -

```
void MyDialog::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if(event->timerId() == m_DialogClose)
    {
        // close the dialog
    }

    else if(event->timerId() == m_RemainingTime)
    {
        // update the relevant QLabel text
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 But a single QTimer with stSingleShot(false), interval 1 sec and a counter would suffice

Comment: @Trompa, yes that's another possible method, though QDialog already includes timer functionality which I'm making use of, so you've no need to handle connecting of the QTimer signal and slots. Either would work. Also, while it's not relevant in this case, I've found using lots of QTimer objects to cause problems, so when it's not required, I try to use the built-in object timers.

Comment: Yup, just giving ideas ;)